# How can I add a last refreshed date visual to my PowerBI report showing the last refreshed time of a data model in Azure Analysis Services

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, azure-analysis-services

### **Context**

I have a PowerBI report held in PowerBI services whose visuals are created using a data model held in an Azure Analysis Services instance (the data model itself is a database inside the azure analysis services instance). The report is using a live connection dataset to the data model which is held in analysis services.
The data model itself has been [deployed using Visual Studio to the Analysis Services instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/deployment/deploy-from-visual-studio-tabular?view=asallproducts-allversions).

The refreshes of the data model are performed using a function app which has functions which refresh the latest 3 daywise partitions. ***Currently in order to view the last refresh time*** we go to the Azure Analysis Services instance on Azure Portal and check the "Date Modified" timestamp field.

As part of my reading I came across the following articles which explain ways in which you can add "last refreshed date" to a PowerBI report (in the form of a visual). However none of these articles specifically mention the effect of having the data model stored in Azure Analysis Services and if this would work in this case.

- [last refresh date & time from SSAS Tabular cube](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/last-refresh-date-amp-time-from-SSAS-Tabular-cube/td-p/1072465)
- [Automatically adding date for last refresh of data](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Automatically-adding-date-for-last-refresh-of-data/td-p/75124)
- [Display Last Refreshed Date in Power BI - The Excelguru Blog](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2016/06/08/display-last-refreshed-date-in-power-bi/)
- [How to Add the Last Refreshed Date and Time to a Power BI Report](https://askgarth.com/blog/how-to-add-the-last-refreshed-date-and-time-to-a-power-bi-report/)
- https://askgarth.com/blog/how-to-display-version-number-info-on-power-bi-reports/

### **Question**

- What's the best way to bring in a "last refreshed datetime" visual into PowerBI if the
  underlying data model is inside Azure Analysis Services and how can this be done?

  - Do these above methods seem plausible and or would these need adapting in my case?
  - Perhaps a different approach would be required?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, adding a calculated column (or calculated table) to your AAS model that stores the NOW() or UTCNOW() function is the correct solution to display the refresh time.

Calculated columns and tables are calculated on refresh and stored in the model.

Comment: [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7297700/david-browne-microsoft) Thanks for the confirmation! What is the best way to add a calculated table in this case if the model was deployed through visual studio? I found this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/create-a-calculated-table-ssas-tabular?view=asallproducts-allversions) **_however_** when I go to "Table > New calculated table" it is greyed out (can't select). Not sure if I am missing something or not.

Comment: [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7297700/david-browne-microsoft) What is the best way to create the calculated table in this case such that it only contains a single value of UTCNOW() or NOW()? What would be the formula expression for the table? Would it it have a calculated column with the UTCNOW() function expression?

Comment: You can always load a single row table from a source query and add a calculated column to it.

Comment: [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7297700/david-browne-microsoft) What's a good way to do that? Say for example "Get Data: on a static table from excel with a single row (with some default value say 1) and then subsequently add a calculated column to that?